# Tkinter error, Class TKApplication implementation in both frameworks error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, frameworks, pycharm

I recently installed Selenium on my Mac. After the install I am unable to get my existing tkinter code to work properly. I don't know if the problem occurred when I installed Selenium or when I installed the Firefox drivers. Prior to the install (I use Pycharm) when I ran the python code that creates my GUI there were no problems but after the install the python code that creates the GUI doesn't work at all, more specifically nothing happens and no GUI is initialized. No error message is given but the tkinter GUI I built doesn't initialize. If I exit Pycharm and try running the code that initializes my GUI from IDLE then all the background code runs but the GUI itself does not appear. Running the GUI code from IDLE does cause the following error message to be displayed:

```
objc[1222]: Class TKApplication is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk (0x108da81f8) and /Users/BioASys/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib (0x115b26e40). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Apparently the Selenium install caused the TKApplication class to be implemented in two different locations and this conflict is causing tkinter to not initialize properly. I've worked through all of the Q&A's I could find on this topic but nothing seems to work. If anybody has any ideas on how I can fix this I would appreciate the help.

Comment: it seems _highly_ unlikely that simply installing selenium would cause this problem. Selenium doesn't at all use tkinter (or visa versa). It appears you're using anaconda, is that right?

Comment: Yes I'm using anaconda. I agree it seems weird that selenium caused this problem but it worked fine before the install and directly after the install it stopped. I believe it may have been caused by the firefox driver install for which I used Homebrew for the first time.

Comment: Using homebrew seems like a pretty significant detail to have left out. When you install something with homebrew, it tends to install lots of other stuff along with it.

Comment: I'm realizing that now but unfortunately I didn't know that yesterday when I installed the Firefox drivers. Any ideas on how to fix the problem would be appreciated. Maybe homebrew has an uninstall function. I'll look at that now

Comment: I tried using Homebrew to uninstall the firefox driver but the problem still remains

Comment: I think you are right, it wasn't the selenium install or the firefox driver install that caused the problem. I tried running my GUI code on another machine and it wouldn't work there which tells me it's not something wrong with the original machine. I then used a backup of my code that is a few days old and it works fine. So somehow I corrupted my code during the Selenium install process in an unexpected way. I'm just going to use my backup code and go from there. Thanks for the dialog it helped me to see the right directions to pursue.